# Add a generic type to a React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created this component:

```js
import { FC } from "react";

export interface Option<T> {
  value: T;
  label: string;
}

interface TestComponentProps {
  name: string;
  options: Option<string>[];
  value: string;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

export const TestComponent: FC<TestComponentProps> = ({
  name,
  options,
  value,
  onChange,
}) => {
  return <div className="">test component</div>;
};
```

and I would like that the generic type of `Option` could be passed from outside, I don't know how but something like this:

```js
export interface Option<T> {
  value: T;
  label: string;
}

interface TestComponentProps<T> {
  name: string;
  options: Option<T>[];
  value: T;
  onChange: (value: T) => void;
}

export const TestComponent: FC<TestComponentProps<T>> = ({
  name,
  options,
  value,
  onChange,
}) => {
  return <div className="">test component</div>;
};
```

This because I would like to have the possibility to create a generic TestComponent that can work for both number and string.

```js
<TestComponent
  name="name 1"
  options={[
   { value: "name1", label: "Name 1" },
   { value: "name2", label: "Name 2" },
  ]}
  value="name1"
  onChange={(v) => console.log("v", v)}
/>

<TestComponent
  name={1}
  options={[
   { value: 1, label: "Name 1" },
   { value: 2, label: "Name 2" },
  ]}
  value={1}
  onChange={(v) => console.log("v", v)}
/>
```

How can I do that?

---

I tried to avoid T and use "string | number":

```js
interface Option<T> {
  value: T;
  label: string;
}

interface TestComponentProps {
  name: string | number;
  options: Option<string | number>[];
  value: string | number;
  onChange: (value: string | number) => void;
}
```

and:

```js
function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestComponent
        name="name 1"
        options={[
          { value: "name1", label: "Name 1" },
          { value: "name2", label: "Name 2" },
        ]}
        value="name1"
        onChange={(c) => setColor(c)}
      />

      <TestComponent
        name={1}
        options={[
          { value: 1, label: "Name 1" },
          { value: 2, label: "Name 2" },
        ]}
        value={1}
        onChange={(v) => console.log("v", v)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

but I get this error:

**Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'**

Comment: If you know that you want to have it as a number or string, there is any reason why you can't just do it simple like this: value: string | number, and do not pass type?

Comment: @mWin take a look at the question. I edited it

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a little bit:

```
interface Option {
  value: string | number;
  label: string;
}

interface TestComponentProps {
  name: string;
  options: Option[];
  value: string | number;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}
```

You have this error, because you define your state type as string:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState("red");
```

By passing as default string, you defined type to string.

So to sort it, you can do one of two things, change available type for onChange param to string like I did above.

Or you can define state type to string | number also:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState<string | number>("red");
```

Comment: Ok but this makes no sense. I know that color is always a string...

Comment: If it is always a string, just use the first version, and define onChange parameter as a string - exactly as in the first part of the code I proposed.  onChange: (value: string) => void; Then you can keep useState like you have it: const [color, setColor] = useState("red");

Comment: but in case of `year`, `onChange` defined as `onChange: (value: string) => void` is wrong since `value` should be a `number`

Comment: There is noting about year in your code. So you want to have a single interface to handle multiple, different states?

Comment: yes, sorry, I mean the second instance of `TestCompoent`. It has a numeric values, instead of string values..

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a single component for two different things, and it is not a good practice. Maybe you can put some context on this, and there is a better solution?

Comment: Sorry, you are right.
Basically the TestComponent should be a wrapper for a dropdown select and the options of a dropdown can be of type string or number